# Excel how to get an average for column for rows that meet multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to know the average days between open and close dates for an item with a close date in a particular month.

So from the below example in Jan 2013 items 2,5 and 6 were closed (Closed can be RESOLVED or CANCELLED status), each were open for 26, 9 and 6 days respectivly. So of the jobs that have a closed date in Jan 2013 (between 01/01/2013 and 13/02/13) they have an average open time (between open and close date) of 13.67 days to 2dp.

I have tried a few ways to get this to work and I think the issue I am having is with the AVERAGE function.

```
Item_ID  Open_Date  Status      Close_Date

1        1/06/2012   RESOLVED   16/07/2012

2        20/12/2012  RESOLVED   16/01/2013

3        2/01/2013   IN PROGRESS

4        3/01/2013   CANCELLED  7/05/2013

5        3/01/2013   RESOLVED   12/01/2013

6        4/01/2013   RESOLVED   10/01/2013

7        1/02/2013   RESOLVED   15/02/2013

8        2/02/2013   OPEN

9        7/02/2013   CANCELLED  26/02/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper column where you calculate the difference between open and closed. Add another helper column where you extract the month number.  Then you can use AverageIfs() for multiple conditions.

If you don't want to use helper columns, you can use a Sumprodcut() formula.

[image]

The formulas for the helper columns, starting in row 2, copied down

E2    `=IF(Sheet1!$D2>0,Sheet1!$D2-Sheet1!$B2,"")`

F2    `=MONTH(Sheet1!$B2)`

In the screenshot, cell H2 uses the helper columns with the formula

```
=AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$10,1,Sheet1!$E$2:$E$10)
```

Cell H4 does not use any helper columns. The formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B2:B10)=1),--(D2:D10<>0),(D2:D10)-(B2:B10))/SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B2:B10)=1),--(D2:D10<>0))
```

[Edit] I just realised that you want to average based on the month the request was closed, so you want to change F2 to

```
=MONTH(Sheet1!$D2)
```

and/or the formula in H4 to

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(D2:D10)=1),--(D2:D10<>0),(D2:D10)-(B2:B10))/SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(D2:D10)=1),--(D2:D10<>0))
```

The result is 14 for both cases.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. Went with the helper columns option. Cheers :)

Comment: @Jess, Glad it helped. Please mark it as the answer, so that people see there is a solution.

Comment: Really helpful – I had a suspicion SUMPRODUCT would work for these sorts of calculations (it always seems to be the answer to my needs). You just need to remember to have the same conditions either side of the division. The “Evaluate formula” tool is really helpful in long formulas like this to see the steps Excel takes.